# Can not instantiate object from web reference in xamarin android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

I'm using a web reference that works as a proxy and i use it for fetching data from sql and write data to sql. When i use it in debug mode, it's work fine without any problem, but in release, as soon as i instantiate an object it's throw an exception that says "object reference not set to an instance of an object".

I should point out that same code worked fine with vs 2015, but since i upgrade to vs 2017 this error occurred.
Also i should mention that:

```
A:I don't use a valid ssl certificate for my web service 
B:I tried URL Behavior of web service in both static and dynamic. 
C:I tried HttpClient Implementation as 'Managed (HttpClientHandler)' and 'Android ClientHandler'
D:I tried SSL/TLS implementation as 'Managed TLS 1.1' and 'Native TLS 1.2+'
E:I tried with and without ServicePointManager for bypass security warnings.

try
{
    WebReference.Register wr = new WebReference.Register(); // in release this line throws an exception
    Toast.MakeText(this, "we reached here", ToastLength.Long).Show(); // in release we never reach to here , but it's fine in debug mode
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Toast.MakeText(this, ex.Message, ToastLength.Long).Show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case in the future anyone else hit's the same problem.

After a whole day, bangin my head against the wall and pulling my hair out, turns out that the 'Use LLVM Optimizing Compiler' option was cause of the problem. Disable this option solved my problem.